# Release modifier keys after using xdotool

Tags: x11, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, xdotool

I use the following command in a bash script file:

```
xdotool type --clearmodifiers $(xclip -o -sel c)
```

I invoke it with a shortcut such as `CTRL+SHIFT+e`

The action works as expected. However, after it completes, the modifier keys remain pressed. That's the problem I need to resolve.

From the xdotool man page, the issue makes some sense:

> *CLEARMODIFIERS*
>   Any command taking the --clearmodifiers flag will attempt to clear any active input modifiers during the command **and restore them afterwards**.

I wish they were not restored, but since they are, **I need an additional command to clear those modifiers**.

Background:

I tried adding these lines at the end of my script file:

```
xdotool keyup Control
xdotool keyup Shift
```

That resulted in me not being able to type or even use the mouse correctly.

I'm using KDE and X11. I use the US International keyboard layout and I have the following keyboard customizations set in KDE system settings:

1. both shift keys together enable caps lock and one shift key disables it
2. Caps Lock as Ctrl

Comment: You could try using `keyup Control keyup Shift` at the start of the xdotool command instead of `--clearmodifiers` which would then not be needed.

Comment: Good idea. I will try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keydown messages for `CTRL+SHIFT+e` (the activator keystrokes) have already been sent and the keyup for the modifier keys do not get sent.

```
sleep 0.2
xdotool keyup Control_L Control_R Shift_L Shift_R
```

The actual key (`e`) may also have to be listed in keyup, but I do not have a problem excluding it.
The sleep command is not always needed, but placing it before every xdotool command helps speed issues because xdotool is fast.